# SQLALCHEMY query on a many to many relationship with map table

Tags: mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a database model (see below). I'm working on a project that should filter query results based on user assigned categories - there can be several categories associated to a user. In other words, I want to show the `User` with `Articles` that matches his/her assigned categories. `Articles` can also be associated with several categories. How can I achieve this using sqlalchemy query?

```
categories_users = db.Table(
    'categories_users',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('category_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
)

categories_articles = db.Table(
    'categories_articles',
    db.Column('article_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('article.id')),
    db.Column('category_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
)

class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    articles = db.relationship('Article', secondary=categories_articles,
        backref=db.backref('categories', lazy='dynamic'))
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    categories = db.relationship('Category', secondary=categories_users,
        backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Answer (score 0):

In a normal m2m you have an association table with join path between the two entities that is clearly defined by foreign keys. As such, you can just tell sqlalchemy which table you want to use to associate two other tables, and it does the rest (As you've done here: `secondary=categories_articles`). Joining `User`'s to `Article`s is *slightly* more complicated.

You want a many to many relationship between `User` and `Article`, so you can get the articles that users are interested in based on common categories. Or simply:

`User` <===> `some join path involving categories` <===> `Article`.

Our `user` table has a foreign key to the `categories_users` table and our `categories_articles` table has a foreign key to our `articles` table. Most importantly, both the `categories_users` table and the `categories_articles` table have the `category_id` field and so we can join those two tables together.

So, you can add an `articles` relationship to your `User` model with the following code:

```
articles = db.relationship(
    'Article',
    secondary=\
        'join(categories_users, categories_articles, '
        'categories_users.c.category_id==categories_articles.c.category_id)'
)
```

Accessing the `User.articles` attribute then emits this SQL:

```
SELECT article.id AS article_id, article.name AS article_name
FROM article, categories_users 
INNER JOIN categories_articles 
ON categories_users.category_id = categories_articles.category_id
WHERE %(param_1)s = categories_users.user_id 
AND article.id = categories_articles.article_id
```

where it's clear to see what is happening. `categories_users` gets joined with `categories_articles` effectively making a new table where `user` rows are combined with `article` rows on their common categories. SQLAlchemy can then treat this as a "normal" many to many relationship with a single association table and leverage the existing foreign keys to piece together the rest of the relationship and construct the necessary query.

Comment: Thank you @SuperShoot... I appreciate your comment. After several tries, I seem to be getting the desired results with: `Article.query.filter(Article.categories.any(Category.id.in_(User.categories)))`